# Cannot find type definition file for 'redux-logger' error in tsconfig.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working in a react application using typescript and redux. I updated several npm packages, between them the `typescript` package and now the `tsconfig.json` (typescrip compiler configuration file) is showing me the following error:

> Cannot find type definition file for 'redux-logger'

I tried to search that issue here and google, but I could not find what I need to include in the tsconfig.json. This is the content of the file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
      "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Am I need to include something new now in the tsconfig.json? The project compiles and runs well, but this error bothers me

[image: error]

And these are the version of npm packages:

```
{
  "name": "documentloader",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.0.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "16.5.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-redux-loading-bar": "^4.0.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts-ts": "latest",
    "react-toastify": "^4.4.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^2.5.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.1",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.5",
    "@types/node": "10.12.0",
    "@types/ramda": "^0.25.39",
    "@types/react": "16.4.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.9",
    "@types/react-redux": "^6.0.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "csstype": "^2.5.7",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "typescript": "^3.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.4.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.9",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.24.3"
  }
 }
```

### Update

Content of @types/redux-logger folder:
[image: folder]

Comment: What line of code is the error reported on?

Comment: First line. I added a print screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error most likely means that the [`typeRoots` mechanism](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types) found a directory that appeared to represent a package named `@types/redux-logger`, but the directory did not contain a declaration file.  If you have an empty directory at `node_modules/@types/redux-logger`, try deleting it.

Comment: It's not empty, but I think the error started happening when I installed the types/redux-logger package, do you recommend me to uninstall it?

Comment: Looks like your directory has `index.d.ts` in it, so you shouldn't be getting the error.  Try restarting VS Code if you haven't already.  You could also try uninstalling and reinstalling the package.

Comment: Yes, reinstalling and restarting VS Code solved the issue, it was a basic solution ;). thank you sir

Comment: I had this same issue with another @type package (@types/babel__generator) and restarting Visual Studio Code worked for me.